# Number of regions in the planar embedding of a connected, $3$-regular graph with $24$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Let $G$ be a connected, $3$-regular, and planar graph with $24$ vertices. How many regions are in a planar embedding of $G$?

Any help to solve this problem would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your approach here would be to use Eulers formula I believe. That is $V - E + F =2$. Remember to look at the outside region as another face.

Comment: As you're told the number of vertices, "3-regular" lets you work out the number of edges.

Comment: Making progress, Anik?

Comment: Yes, using Euler's formula, I have $F=3$, for $K_{2,3}$ and from that, $G$ has $14$ planar regions. Thank you both for your hints!

Comment: You could write that up, and post it as an answer, Anik.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, to help the next person who comes along with a similar question.

Comment: Yeah, I just did. I hope it's right @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler's formula, we know that

$V-E+F=2$

For $K_{2,3}$, $V=5$, $E=6$. Hence,

$5-6+F=2$, which means $F=3$

Now $G$ is $3$-regular. Hence $d(v) = 3 \\ \forall v \in V$

Now $2|E| = \sum_{v \in V}d(v) =3 \times24 \implies |E|=36$

Here, $E=36, V=24$

By Euler's formula, $F=2-V+E=2-24+36=14$

Comment: Good! But the part about $K_{2,3}$ seems irrelevant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson and why is that?

Comment: Well, if you cut it out, and just left the part starting with "Now $G$ is $3$-regular," wouldn't that be a complete answer to the question as posted?